# Find all bolded fonts and select them?(recorded macros are not valid)

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to find all bold fonts with VBA? Without any editing, I just want to select all these bold fonts. I can do it with Word's own "Find and Replace" function, but recording a macro has no effect.

The desired effect is as follows.

[image: The desired effect]

The following code is the recorded macro, which is not valid.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Although it should not be difficult to implement this function, I have searched the web for many days without finding the right answer.

Comment: A problem with this is that Bold, in Word, is a toggle. Thus you can have .Bold=False for text which appears Bold and Bold = True for text that appears not bold. Instead of Bold, in my documents, I use the character style Strong which in most style sets produces Bold. That is not a toggle.

Comment: I don't think you can select multiple non-continuous range using VBA so is selecting the last action you need to do?

Comment: In your screen shot the matches are *not* selected, they are highlighted.